# Excursion and combination problem

Tags: combinations

From a group of 12 students 8 are to be chosen for an excursion.  There are 3 students who decide that either all of them will join or none of them will join. In how many ways can the 8 be chosen. ...Is it 9C5+9C8 or 9C5-9C8 Please clarify

Comment: You want to add the two cases where all 3 are included and where none of the 3 are included.

Comment: $\binom{9}{5}$ counts the number of groups that have all the  fussy ones, and $\binom{9}{8}$ counts the number of choices where they are left behind, as they should be.  To get the total we add.

Comment: Okay I am convinced